# Limit physical memory usage of process (to keep system responsive)?

Tags: memory-management, windows-7, limit

Though similar questions have been discussed here and elsewhere, I couldn't find a solution to the following problem. Under Windows 7 Professional (64 bit), I'm working on an application which temporarily needs much more virtual memory than available physical memory. To simulate this, I wrote a small program basically doing this:

```
size_t sum = 0;
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> data(new unsigned char[size]);

for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    data[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);

for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    sum += data[i];
```

It can be observed in the task manager that memory usage quickly increases during the first loop (when the memory reserved by "new" actually gets committed). As soon as the memory curve hits the physical memory limit, the system becomes unusable (not even the mouse cursor is moving anymore).

The question is how can I prevent the process from consuming all physical memory such that sufficient memory remains available to other processes to keep responsive. I thought that SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx() with the QUOTA_LIMITS_HARDWS_MAX_ENABLE flag would solve this issue, but it doesn't. Although the working set size of the process stays below the limit according to the resource monitor, the memory usage curve in the task manager is the same as without SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx(), and the system becomes unresponsive when physical memory is exhausted.

I don't mind if the process itself performs less than optimal due to page faults, but it should not affect the entire system. Do you have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Working set != memory usage. You can limit memory usage by setting the `ProcessMemoryLimit` member of the [`JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure and setting the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY` flag.

Comment: I tried both `ProcessMemoryLimit` with `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY` and `JobMemoryLimit` with `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY`, but none of them worked. With any of these limits, I get a `bad allocation` exception, i.e., the limits apply to virtual memory instead of physical memory. I want my process to be able to get as much virtual memory (i.e., physical memory + swap space) as available on the system, but at no time use more than a given amount amount of physical memory.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to limit commit.